# Suppose $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ are roots of $(11 - x)^3 + (13 - x)^3 - (24 - 2x)^3$ . What is the sum of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, problem-solving, factoring

> Suppose $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ are roots of $(11 - x)^3 + (13 - x)^3 - (24 - 2x)^3$ . What is the sum of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ ?

**What I Tried** :- I expanded the expression and got :-
$$ \rightarrow (11^3 + 13^3 + 24^3) - 10x^3 - 33x(11 - x) - 39x(13 - x) - 144x(24 - 2x)$$
$$ \rightarrow 17352 - 10x^3 + (33 + 39 + 288)x^2 - (363 + 507 + 3456)x $$
$$ \rightarrow -10x^3 + 360x^2 - 4326x + 17352 $$

Now on Wolfram Alpha I get that this can be factorised as $(-2)(x - 12)(5x^2 - 120x + 723)$ , hence these are the $x_1,x_2,x_3$.
So $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 5x^2 - (120 - 1)x + (723 - 12 - 2)$ .

$\rightarrow 5x^2 - 119x + 713$ .

I hope this is the final answer , and I went through a lot of calculations, so this method of getting the answer is definitely not that simple . I am seeking a far more easier way or a shortcut to do this problem , can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you know Vieta's formulae? The answer cannot contain $x$ because it's a dummy variable.

Comment: Oh true , I know Vieta's Formula , also what I did is completely incorrect . $(-2)$ definitely can't be a root

Comment: If you mean $=$ write $=$, there's no "implies" here.

Comment: If you know Vieta's formulae then you should know the answer is just $-360/(-10)=36$ from the coefficients of the expanded expression.

Comment: Aah Yeah Right I am actually stupid doing all these .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Writing expression $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ as: $$a\left(x-x_{1}\right)\left(x-x_{2}\right)\left(x-x_{3}\right)$$
reveals that the coefficient of $x^{2}$ takes value: $$-a\left(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$a^3+b^3-(a+b)^3=-3ab(a+b)$$

Comment: This is my way$(+1)$

Answer (score 2):

In general, Vieta's formulas for a polynomial $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ of degree $n>0$ state that the sum of all roots is equal to
$$x_1+\cdots+x_n=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}.$$
Hence we need the coefficients next to $x^3$ and $x^2$, which are 6 and -216, respectively (and not $-10$ and $360$ according to your expansion). Hence the sum is
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=-\frac{-216}{6}=36.$$

Comment: Your answer is correct , but I didn't quite understand why you got $6x^3 - 216x^2$ in your expansion .

Comment: @SouradipDas the first and the second term each contribute $-x^3$. The third term contributes $-8x^3$ but there is a minus in front of it, so it contributes $8x^3$. In total, that's $6x^3$. My guess is that you've missed a minus sign somewhere. You can verify the expansion in e.g. WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 1):

***First method (solve equation)***

Using the formula:$$a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
We have:
$$(11-x)^3+(13-x)^3-(24-2x)^3=(11-x)^3+(13-x-24+2x)((13-x)^2+(13-x)(24-2x)+(24-2x)^2)=(11-x)^3-(11-x)(7x^2-172x+1057)=(11-x)((11-x)^2-7x^2+172x-1057)=(x-11)(6x^2-150x+936)=(x-11)(x-12)(x-13)$$

Then we have:
$$x_1=11; x_2=12; x_3=13 \Rightarrow x_1+x_2+x_3=11+12+13=36$$

***Second method (Vieta's formula)***

General Vieta's formula looks like:
$$\sum_{1\leq i_1<...<i_k\leq n}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k} r_{i_j} \right)=(-1)^k \frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}$$

Then, for cubic polynomial:
$$a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 = 0$$

The sum of roots is equal to:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=-\frac{a_2}{a_3}$$

That's because we interested only in coefficients near $x^3$ and $x^2$.
$$(11-x)^3=-x^3+33x^2-...$$
$$(13-x)^3=-x^3+39x-...$$
$$(24-2x)^3=-8x^3+288x^2-...$$

Then:
$$(11-x)^3+(13-x)^3-(24-2x)^3=6x^3-216x^3-...\Rightarrow a_3=6;a_2=-216.$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=-\frac{a_2}{a_3}=\frac{216}{6}=36$$

Answer (score 0):

**I used this method**

We know that
if $$a + b + c = 0,$$ then: $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 3abc.$$

Now if we cleverly assign values to a, b, and c,
$$a = 11 - x$$
$$b=13-x$$
$$c=-(24-2x)=-24+2x$$

We have:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = 0 = 3abc$$

So:
$$3(11-x)(13-x)(-24+2x)=0$$

The roots of this equation are:
$$x_1 = 11$$
$$x_2=13$$
$$x_3 = 12$$

The answer is: $$x_1+x_2+x_3=11+13+12=36$$